Specify environment variables for grafana-a-deployment in grafana-a CR with Grafana Operator in OpenShift
With the community-provided Grafana Operator in OpenShift, how can we configure the Custom Resource (CR) grafana-a to pass environment variables (e.g. NO_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY) to the Deployment grafana-a-deployment?
In our environment, grafana-a-deployment will break without these environment variables. We can of course edit the YAML config for this Deployment to use these environment variables, which works temporarily until grafana-a overwrites the config, then the Deployment fails again.
Attempting to implement the method here does not actually make any change to the CR.
Grafana community-provided Operator version 5.9.2 running in OpenShift 4.12.45

There is a page on the Grafana Operator documentation on using Secrets as credentials for the grafana-a-deployment Deployment. However if you want to configure NO_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY without using Secrets, you can configure the spec.deployment entry like this:
spec:
  deployment:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: NO_PROXY
                  value: '<URLs>'
                - name: HTTPS_PROXY
                  value: '<URL>'
              name: grafana

After saving the configuration, the grafana-a-deployment Deployment will immediately be updated to always have the NO_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variable values specified.
